# How to split address column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have an address column in a dataframe like below:

```
Address
101 Marietta Street NorthWest Atlanta GA 30303
```

Now I want to split it into 4 diff columns like

```
Address                          City        State     Zip
101 Marietta Street NorthWest    Atlanta     GA        30303
```

It is guaranteed that the last value in address column will be zip code, second last will be state, third last will be city and remaining will be address. So I am thinking, I can split address column values with space and extract values from rear.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the logic to separate it into 4 different columns? Would last 3 words be in last 3 columns? So `tidyr::extract(df, Address, c("Address", "City", "State", "Zip"), regex = "(.*) (\\w+) (\\w+) (\\w+)$")` . would work ?

Comment: @RonakShah I think the 1st group can use `+` instead of `*`.

Comment: @RonakShah I have edited my question to include logic

Comment: You could use some regex patterns to identify the zip code pretty easily, and the state abbreviation either by having 2 capital letters together, or from a lookup table. But I'm not sure what your logic will be for splitting addresses from cities. If there's a limited set of cities, you might make a lookup table of a ton of city names. Even this example is tough because often an address will have the form "123 S Data Street", but here you have an address that doesn't end with "Street", "Avenue", etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `tidyr::extract` to get last 3 words in separate columns and remaining text as `Address`

```
tidyr::extract(df, Address, c("Address", "City", "State", "Zip"), 
                   regex = "(.+) (\\w+) (\\w+) (\\w+)")

#                        Address    City State   Zip
#1 101 Marietta Street NorthWest Atlanta    GA 30303
```

Comment: While working on the provided sample data, this will probabaly fail if the city is someting like `Los Angeles` or `New York`.

Comment: @Wimpel yes but I am just following OP's logic in the post.

Comment: @Wimpel it is indeed failing for such cities. I didn't think of such cases while coming up with logic. Is there any way to fix it?